# How to read the actual date in ROS

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!,
I would like to name some archives, which I create in a ROS node, with a string related to the actual date on which the node is called. I already have used Ros time, but I dont know what does this "absolute" time means.
My code is:

```
ros::Time begin = ros::Time::now();
ROS_INFO("%d\n", begin.sec);
```

And the output is:

```
[ INFO] [1508853591.867555047, 1508853591.867143646]: 1508853591
```

My questions are, what does this "1508853591" means? And how could I get something like 24-10-2017-16:13 or like it?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273953/how-to-read-the-actual-date-in-ros/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2017-10-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may not look like it, but you already have "the actual date" there. It's just encoded as a [*Unix Timestamp* or epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which is:

> the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

To convert it into a date-time string, see #q251966, or lookup any of the myriad ways to convert a Unix epoch into any other date-time representation. This is not ROS specific, so don't limit your searches to pages about it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2017-10-26**:
Thanks! That was exactly what i needed.